# How not to push a particular folder to the remote repo?

Tags: git

I have a project with Ruby on Rails and local files, images in this case, are stored in the path `/public/system`. I included that line in `.gitignore` but every time I push changes to the remote repository the images are uploaded to github anyway.

Why?

I just want this folder and its content not to be uploaded to github, but I do want to keep the files in my local repo.

This is my `.gitignore` file, it's just the default content, I added the last line:

```
# See https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files for more about ignoring files.
#
# If you find yourself ignoring temporary files generated by your text editor
# or operating system, you probably want to add a global ignore instead:
#   git config --global core.excludesfile '~/.gitignore_global'

# Ignore bundler config.
/.bundle

# Ignore the default SQLite database.
/db/*.sqlite3
/db/*.sqlite3-journal

# Ignore all logfiles and tempfiles.
/log/*
!/log/.keep
/tmp

/public/system
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Making git "forget" about a file that was tracked but is now in .gitignore](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274057/making-git-forget-about-a-file-that-was-tracked-but-is-now-in-gitignore)

Comment: I saw that answer, but I am not asking that exactly, I am updating my post to clarify

Comment: you _are_ asking that exactly.  What doesn't work about the top answer there?  It is literally the same command as the answer you just selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once one of the files is committed (remember that git doesn't care about folders), adding them to the `.gitignore` file is not retroactive. You will have to remove them using this command

`git rm --cached public/system`

It will only remove them from git index, not in your local modifications therefore the folder will still exist in your file system.

Comment: That worked! However, what if I run `git add -A .` again? Would that start keeping track of the folder again? I guess it would right? What can I do to avoid this?

Comment: Once you've committed the 'deletion' outlined by @aduch and your `.gitignore` file, they should be ignored permanently. You can test this by using `git status` - they shouldn't show up as untracked files.